# C++ IntelliSense 'auto' feature? Where is it? How to get it 'on'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, intellisense

I would like to enable the [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) 'auto' feature (like the Visual Studio C# 2008 Express) but I am using Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express Edition and in the Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ (there is no option 'IntelliSense' (like Visual C#). How do I get this feature enabled? I know I can get a shortcut in place (CTRL-space etc...)? But how do I get it automatically (the drop down menu)?

Comment: Intellisense has a lot of functionality. Which exact feature is it you're interested in?

Comment: If i get this right he wants the code completion drop down to pop up automatically, without pressing ctrl+space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, IntelliSense is turned on by default (and AFAIK there isn't even an official way to turn it off). However, when you're coming from C#, you might think it's turned off, because it's so much less powerful in C++. (The reason for this is that C++ is much, much harder to parse. You can find more information on the subject [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379615%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/02/29/intellisense-part-2-the-future.aspx).)

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com) improves C++ considerably (although it might not be all that considerably when you're used to C#), but I don't think you can install plugins in the express edition.

Comment: Your guess is correct - Visual Assist will not work on the Express Edition.

Answer (score 5):

This should be enabled by default. But sometimes for C++ projects it stops working.

Is there a .NCB file in your project folder? If so, close your solution, delete that file, and then re-open your solution and do a rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

I use VC++ 2008 Express Edition as my primary environment.  All I can say is that sometimes Intellisense works wonderfully, sometimes it doesn't work at all.  The Intellisense parser seems to be slow as can be and stumbles over a lot of cases, especially when templates are involved.  Sadly, I just don't think you can count on it being consistently available.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that *sometimes* helps when intellisense doesn't do what it should, is to delete the .ncb file in the project folder in order to force VS to rebuild the internal database (close VS before deleting the file).